# Multiple Histograms in one Visualization

Tags: pivot, data-visualization, tableau-api

I would like to know how to make a histogram with multiple measures. My data is a Monte Carlo simulation that shows for 6 default rates and 5000 simulations what gross profit turns out to be. Just to reiterate, for each default rate in my excel sheet there are 5000 rows. Each bar in the histogram shows for example: 10% of the time gross profit falls between 70M and 80M. The below picture shows the histogram working for 5% default rate, I would also like to add every other rate then color code them.

[image: One default Rate]

Here is the input:
[image: input]

Comment: Please include some sample data so that your problem can be tried upon.

Comment: I just did @AnilGoyal, thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to restructure your data before proceeding further- (demonstration on some sample data)

- select all rate columns in <kbd>Data</kbd> tab and click `pivot`

[image]

- Rename the new columns as per taste (say `Rate` for names and `values` for another
- Add/create bins on `value` column and add `rate` to color, you may get desired view-

either

[image]

OR

[image]